# Adding translation in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, gettext

I've create a plugin for wordpress and now I want translate it.
I've adding in my code .po and .mo files in "Plugin-name/locale" (I've create "locale" folder where I put de_DE, fr_FR, en_US, it_IT, es_ES, ru_RU folders)
Every language folder contains a folder called "LC_MESSAGES" containing .po and .mo file like "translation.mo and transolation.po"
Now I want connect these translation.
In my Config file I've created something like this:

```
    $locale = str_replace("-", "_", $culture);

    $textDomain = "translation";
    try {
        @putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    }
    catch (Exception $e) { }
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale . ".utf8"); //Set language
    bindtextdomain($textDomain, dirname(__FILE__) . "/locale"); //Specify location of translation tables
    textdomain($textDomain); //Choose domain
```

and in my page I've just added the gettext like:

```
_("Hello")
```

My site is in italian so I will see "Ciao" but the plugin doesn't take the translation so I see still "Hello"

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Opcache active?

Comment: it wasn't active but now i've activated it but still not workin

Comment: No. Keep it off for developing. It caches PHP files and when you change them you don't see the changes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

With Wordpress you need to be using this format normally:
either

```
_e( 'your_text_to_be_translated' );
```

or

```
__( 'your_text_to_be_translated' );
```

Comment: I've tried wit _e( and __( but still not workin.. I don't know if i miss something for connecting my translation or what

Comment: you could try this plugin instead very easy to use:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

Comment: but i don't wanna recreate every translation

Comment: you don't have to as it uses the same .po .mo .pot translation files

Comment: ok but if I do this i have to do in every site where i install my plugin?